# apache jackrabbit with mongodb and jboss issue

Tags: java, rmi, jackrabbit

my code is

```
Repository repository = new URLRemoteRepository("http://localhost:8088/rmi");
    //  Repository repository = JcrUtils.getRepository();
    Session session = repository.login(new SimpleCredentials("admin", "admin".toCharArray()));
        Node root = session.getRootNode(); 
        System.out.println("get root node..");
        // Store content 
        Node hello = root.addNode("hello55555555555"); 
        Node world = hello.addNode("world"); 
        world.setProperty("message", "Hello, World!"); 
        session.save(); 
        System.out.println("repository accessed successfully......");
```

i getting following error

get root node..
org.apache.jackrabbit.rmi.client.RemoteRepositoryException: java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.jackrabbit.rmi.value.StringValue; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -6456025645604163205, local class serialVersionUID = 220963478492833703

Comment: You'd need to add more information. Versions? And what exactly is running on that URL?

Comment: You have different versions of Jackrabbit at client and server. Jackrabbit via RMI is very poorly thought out and implemented. For  example they seem to think it is clever to substitute a non-working stub any time they get an RMI error. It isn't. It means once you get one error it will never work again. You can fix this by it takes some trouble. I would advise against it if possible.